# How to set text content with SimpleXML's XPath support?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

```
<xml>
    <ns:foo attribute="bar">
        OLD TEXT DATA
    </ns:foo>
</xml>
```

I use XPath to handle the XML namespaces. This won't work:

```
$xml->asXML('old.xml');

foreach ($xml->xpath('ns:foo') as $foo) {
    $foo['attribute'] = 'new bar';
    $foo = 'NEW TEXT DATA'; //This won't be saved by asXML().
}

$xml->asXML('new.xml');
```

How could I change the text content with [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml->asXML('old.xml');

foreach ($xml->xpath('ns:foo') as $foo) {
    $foo['attribute'] = 'new bar';
    $foo[0] = 'NEW TEXT DATA';
}

$xml->asXML('new.xml');
```